# iPod touch 4, white screen, not showing up in iTunes even in DFU mode

Tags: ipod-touch

I have a 4th gen Touch. All it currently shows is a white screen if you press either the home or power button, and it turns back off after 5 seconds (similar to if it were on an iOS lock screen). Holding down the power button for 3 seconds to bring down the slide to power off menu, it still shows a white screen but now the buttons don't turn off the screen (as it should).

I remember we already tried to get the screen replaced, it still showed white. iTunes doesn't recognize it at all and the screen doesn't light up nor does it make a charging sound when it's plugged in, although it definitely is charging. Nothing shows on the screen while it's booting up. I have tried DFU mode, it appears to work as now the screen displays absolutely nothing, but it still doesn't get recognized.

What could be causing this, and if possible, how could I fix it?

Comment: Did this iPod ever work? - If so, what happened before it stopped working? (liquid? dropped? other?)

Comment: Yes, it was working. Wanted to use it again sometime in 2013, only for it to give me this.